# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Tags: java, rmi, policy, securitymanager

I met this issue and tried for long time, still couldn't solve it. All the solutions in similar topics in stackoverfflow have been tried but not useful for me. Any help would be really appreciate!!

Errors:

```
Set initial logic: Analyzer_ADD
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:AnalyzerLogicAdd (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.loadLogicFromRepository(Unknown Source)
at exampleSAS.logicRepository.LocalLogicRepository.loadLogicFromRepository(LocalLogicRepository.java:61)
at exampleSAS.adaptationLogic.AdaptationLogicService.implementLogic(AdaptationLogicService.java:50)
at exampleSAS.MainStarter.main(MainStarter.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AnalyzerLogicAdd (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

I have both server.policy file in RMI server project, and client.policy in RMI client project:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission ;
};
```

and I specified VM arguments for server project:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\workspace\Repository\ -Djava.security.policy=C:\workspace\Repository\server.policy
```

for client project:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\workspace\Repository\ -Djava.security.policy=C:\workspace\SAS\client.policy
```

And the starter code for server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);

System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "AllPermission.policy");

//create a local instance of the object and export the service
LogicRepository rep = LogicRepository.getInstance();
ILogicRepository stub = (ILogicRepository)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(rep, 0);

Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
registry.rebind(SasConstants.LOGIC_REPOSITORY, stub);
System.out.println("Logic Repository has been started");

} catch (RemoteException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

I know here are duplicated policy setting with VM arguments, but even I delete this it still doesn't work.

Somehow I think the security manager is not working, could anyone please help here?

The server could launch normally, and client could also call simple method like helloWorld in server, but when I tried to return an object, the errors come out.

Many thanks!
Regards,Tony

After adding setSecurityManager, I got error "access denied". The code and error are following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);

System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "AllPermission.policy");

if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());   
        }
......
```

Error stack:

```
access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\workspace\Repository\bin" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
access: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "TONYYANG70FC" "resolve")
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Unknown Source)
at LogicRepositoryStarter.main(LogicRepositoryStarter.java:37)
access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy")
access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\workspace\Repository\bin" "read")
access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain  (file:/C:/workspace/Repository/bin/ <no signer certificates>)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@387f44 
<no principals>
java.security.Permissions@17c264 (
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read")
("java.io.FilePermission" "\C:\workspace\Repository\bin\-" "read")
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM")
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread")
("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")
)


access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.hostname" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "sun.rmi.runtime.RuntimeUtil.getInstance")
access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jdk.net.ephemeralPortRange.low" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.net")
access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\net.dll" "read")
access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jdk.net.ephemeralPortRange.high" "read")
access: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at LogicRepositoryStarter.main(LogicRepositoryStarter.java:38)
access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy")
access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\workspace\Repository\bin" "read")
access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain  (file:/C:/workspace/Repository/bin/ <no signer certificates>)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@387f44
<no principals>
java.security.Permissions@81197d (
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read")
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read")
("java.io.FilePermission" "\C:\workspace\Repository\bin\-" "read")
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM")
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread")
("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")
)

Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at LogicRepositoryStarter.main(LogicRepositoryStarter.java:38)
```

With more information which better expose this issue:

In the client, I successfully called the methods of the server class:

print() which just says hello world

loadLogicFromRepository(type, logicID)

Client code:

```
protected ILogicRepository server;
private void initializeRMI() {
    Registry registry;
    try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        server = (ILogicRepository) registry.lookup(FesasConstants.LOGIC_REPOSITORY);
    } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

try {
        //TODO: check, that the correct meta data is used (string with the ID at the beginning)
        server.print();
        return server.loadLogicFromRepository(type, logicID);
    } catch (RemoteException | LogicNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

code for server.loadLogicFromRepository :

```
public ILogic loadLogicFromRepository(LogicType type, String logicID) throws RemoteException, LogicNotFoundException {

    AnalyzerLogicAdd logic  =new AnalyzerLogicAdd();

    return logic;
}
```

It does nothing but just return an object of another server class AnalyzerLogicAdd, which implements serialisable interface

And this object is very important for me to get from server.

Comment: Your security debug trace shows that `AllPermission` was not in effect, which can only mean that your .policy file was not found.

Comment: I added 'System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.security.policy"));
   System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase"));' and it points to the correct policy file and codebase path

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved the security issue, it is the path missing "src", sorry for stupid error. But I still get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when trying to return an object of server class AnalyzerLogicAdd. It seems the client doesn't have the class definition of it, how shall I solve this please?

Comment: could this also be codebase URL issue? is this setting correct? -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\workspace\Repository\src\

Comment: The reason of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException is URL should be Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\workspace\Repository\bin\ ,not ...\src\

Comment: URLs use forward slashes, not backward slashes, but a `file:` URL won't work unless both client and server are running in the same host, in which case it is rather difficult to see the point of using the codebase feature at all. The codebase feature is a *software distribution* solution. Codebase URLs normally use HTTP or FTP.

Comment: Thank you! @EJP. If I try to adapt it into intranet, both server and client run Windows. What shall I do then please? Need to change Something regarding createRegistry and rebind I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just defining a security policy doesn't install a security manager. You have to do that explicitly, and afterwards.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. But actually I tried with explicitly set up a security manager, but in this way the server even couldn't start up. the error stack trace is added above. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: I can't understand why I still get access denied after set allPermission. I am currently running it at a win 7 virtual machine on my Mac. Could this influence?

Comment: But I tried on a win pc and still same issue, so nothing to do win 7 virtual machine

Comment: You have to install the security manager after setting the policy, as my answer says. If you still get access exceptions, the policy file probably wasn't found. Run it with -Djava,security.debug=access,failure to see exactly what access failed and what policy was in effect when it did so.

Comment: you see from error stack, the details about security policy is already listed, as I already put -Djava,security.debug=access,failure there. I don't know why I got  access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "TONYYANG70FC" "resolve").